# Send email via Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, smtp, powershell-2.0

How can I send the **result of a Powershell (v 2.0) script** by using **IP address and port number** of an SMTP server (e.g xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xx) with **anonymous authentication** which **does not require secure connection**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small script, don't forget, you are on the top of the .NET framework:

```
Param([string[]] $to = $(throw "Please Specify a destination !"),
      [string] $subject = "<No Subject>",
      [string] $body = $(throw "Pleasr specify a content !"),
      [string] $smtpHost = $(throw "Please specify a SMTP server !"),
      [string] $from = $(throw "Please specify from email address !")
)

## Message creation
$email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

## Fill the fields
foreach($mailTo in $to)
{
  $email.To.Add($mailTo)
}

$email.From = $from
$email.Subject = $subject
$email.Body = $body

## Send the message
$client = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtpHost
$client.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$client.Send($email)
```